# Why is the wrong button showing up in my contacts app?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts

My iPhone randomly decided to lose all phone contacts from the address book.

Following these instructions to re-instate them...

1. Settings > iCloud
2. Turn Contacts (sync) OFF, then back ON
3. Go into Contacts app and click top-left refresh button.

...

It's not a refresh button, it says "Groups"...what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the [latest instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203521) to refresh your contacts on your device:

> To refresh your contacts:
>
> 1. Open the Contacts app and tap Groups in the upper-left corner.
> 2. Swipe down on the list to refresh your groups.

Additionally, since you use iCloud, you may want to check your contacts by using the iCloud website.